# How to check if a value exists in a column using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Ive been trying to do this for a system using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. I have a table morAtt

columns = Date,Name,Position,TimeIn,TimeOut

If (value in column exists) then

sql = UPDATE morAtt set TimeOut = TimeString

Else

sql = INSERT INTO morAtt (Date,Name,Position,TimeIn) values (DateString,txtName.Text,txtPost.Text,TimeString)

EndIf

So, I need help on how to check if a value exists in a column, if a name exists then update the TimeOut, else the name doesn't exists insert into table a new row of a staff.

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

```
UPDATE morAtt a
SET a.TimeOut = TimeString
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM morAtt b
    WHERE (b.Name= a.Name)
)
```

or

```
if morAtt .name is not null then update else insert
```